# UI testing functions within test Class

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, xcode8

I am implementing UI testing and I have created a 900 lines test class.  This file contains 16 different tests that I would like to have lest separately in the left pane so that I can run specific ones as required.  However, when I include the 16 funcs there are no tests listed.  When I comment out the 16 funcs, I can see (and run) all the tests as a single line.

Here is the structure of the 16 funcs.

```
import XCTest
class zeroCounts: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        XCUIApplication().launch()
    }
    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    } 

    func tests() {
        testsRun = 0
        currentRow  = 0

    func case_0000() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_0001() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_0010() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_0011() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_0100() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_0101() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_0110() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_0111() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1000() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1001() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1010() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1011() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1100() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1101() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1110() {
        // Do stuff
    }
    func case_1111() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this problem, rename your test functions to begin with `test`. The  test runner will find those functions and show them in the navigation panel just like you want.

```
func test_1111() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: That was the issue, thanx!